# How do I multiply a map of a variable in Python?

Tags: python, maps

Here's my code:

```
elif cmd == "pay for dog":
    name = input("Dog name? ")
        for d in dogs:
            if d["name"] == name:
                print(d["name"] + " owes $" + d["days"])
```

How do I multiply d["days"] so that the person has to pay $30 each day? What I really mean is, how do I multiply d["days"] by 30?

Comment: Please format your code with 4 extra spaces in front of each line so people can better understand what you mean

Comment: Should I give you the rest of my code, incase some other part is messing it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, `d["days"]` is string.

Try this:

```
print(d["name"] + " owes $" + str(30 * int(d["days"])))
```

or this:

```
print("%s owes $%d" % (d["name"], (30 * int(d["days"]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use casting. Assuming `d["days"]` is a number, `print("$"+str(d["days"]*30))` will show you the amount to pay.

Comment: I tried your way. It said "owes $333333333333333333333333333333", which is how it responds if d["days"] = 3.

Comment: But what is the type of d["days"] ? I think it might be a string instead of an int. This way, the string "3" is repeated 30 times.

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstand you correctly, you want

```
print("%s owes $%.2f" % (d["name"], (30 * float(d["days"]))))
```

Comment: It said "owes $333333333333333333333333333333", which is how it responds if d["days"] = 3.

Comment: @person d["days"] seems to be a string in your case  - now my answer is more general

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the needful

```
for d in dogs:
    if d['name'] == name:
        print(d['name']+ " owes $" +str(int(d['day']) * 30))
```

Comment: It said "owes $333333333333333333333333333333", which is how it responds if d["days"] = 3.

Comment: if the value is not integer then wrap it with int()